# Mostrar registro en tabla Bootstrap usando Ajax Jquery C# - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Tengo una duda al momento de mostrar mis registros de mi base de datos en mi tabla de Bootstrap 4, al inspeccionarlo me devuelve los datos esperados, pero por alguna razón no me los muestra en mi tabla.

Este es mi codigo de mi **tabla html**

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tablaCdo">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Linea</th>
                <th>Lunes</th>
                <th>Martes</th>
                <th>Miercoles</th>
                <th>Jueves</th>
                <th>Viernes</th>
                <th>Sabado</th>
                <th>Domingo</th>
                <th>Total Semanal</th>
                <th>Turnos</th>
                <th>Producción Semanal</th>
                <th>Producción Mnesual</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

y el siguiente código es mi función en donde llamo a un **Ajax**:

```js
 $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/CDO/cargarSemana",
                data: {"Id": Id},
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var row;
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        row += "<tr>"
                                  + "<td>" + value.Id + "</td>"
                                  + "<td>" + value.fecha + "</td>"
                                  + "<td>" + value.parte + "</td>"
                                  + "<td>" + value.capacidad + "</td>"
                             + "</tr>";
                    });
                    $('#tablaCdo tbody').append(row);
                }
            })
        })
```

y en mi **Controlador** tengo mi consulta en donde selecciono mis datos de la base de datos:

```html
public String cargarSemana()
        {
            Query q = new Query()
                .Sel("cdoDetalle", "Id", "parte", "capacidad", "fecha", "tableroOTLineaFamilia_Id") 
                .From("cdoDetalle")
                .OrderBy("Id", Constructor.dbOrd.Desc);

            List<tableroOTCDO> cdo = Tools.Connection.App.ExecList<tableroOTCDO>(q);

            int draw = 1;
            int start = 0;
            int length = cdo.Count();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
            {
                    status = true,
                    mensaje = "Datos cargados",
                    data = cdo,
                    draw = draw,
                    recordsTotal = cdo.Count(),
            });
        }
```

pero no logro de mostrar los datos en mi tabla de bootstrap.

Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor!

Comment: Hola, por lo que veo cuando generas tu objeto en json metes los datos de tu consulta en una propiedad llamada data por lo cual seria necesario que en tu ajax recorras data.data.

`$.each(data.data, function (index, value) {...`

Comment: ¿es posible que sea que el numero de columnas que estas asignando al body en la carga Ajax no sea el mismo que el numero de cabeceras th?

Comment: Que Framework utilizas? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta estoy utilizando ASP.NET MVC con Entity Framework

Comment: @Raúl ok, entonces el numero de columnas debe ser igual al numero de la cabeceras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás utilizando ASP.NET MVC, la forma correcta de devolver un contenido JSON a la Vista desde el Controlador, es utilizando la clase **`JsonResult`**.

Modifica la Acción `cargarSemana()` de esta manera:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult cargarSemana()
    {
        Query q = new Query()
            .Sel("cdoDetalle", "Id", "parte", "capacidad", "fecha", "tableroOTLineaFamilia_Id")
            .From("cdoDetalle")
            .OrderBy("Id", Constructor.dbOrd.Desc);

        List<tableroOTCDO> cdo = Tools.Connection.App.ExecList<tableroOTCDO>(q);

        int draw = 1;
        int start = 0;
        int length = cdo.Count();

        var jsonObj = new
        {
            status = true,
            mensaje = "Datos cargados",
            data = cdo,
            draw = draw,
            recordsTotal = cdo.Count(),
        };

        return Json(jsonObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Genial!! me ha funcionado, gracias!!

Comment: @EdgarRojas: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, 
y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, 
con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Comment: si, ya marque el check verde a tu respuesta que me ayudo a solucionar mi problema. Muchas gracias!